# Finding eigenstates of $S_x$ using Stern Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematics

*Quantum mechanics, McIntyre, pg 62*

[image]

For above spin $1$ Stern Gerlach experiment a set of results is
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\mathcal{P}_{1 x}=\left.\left.\right|_{x}\langle 1 \mid 1\rangle\right|^{2}=\frac{1}{4} \\
\mathcal{P}_{0 x}=\left.\left.\right|_{x}\langle 0 \mid 1\rangle\right|^{2}=\frac{1}{2} \\
\mathcal{P}_{-1 x}=\left.\right|_{x}\left\langle-\left.1|1\rangle\right|^{2}=\frac{1}{4},\right.
\end{array}
$$
as illustrated in Fig. 2.12. These experimental results can be used to determine the $S_{x}$ eigenstates in terms of the $S_{z}$ basis
$$
\begin{array}{l}
|1\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{2}|-1\rangle \\
|0\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-1\rangle \\
|-1\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{2}|-1\rangle
\end{array}
$$

To find the $S_{x}$ eigenstates in terms of the $S_{z}$ basis I need two more similar experiments in which the input to Sx analyzer are  $0,-1$ spin particles respectively.

However I am getting a sign ambiguity while using the experimental results.

Below are two expressions which both are in line with the experiments:

1. $$|1\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{2}|-1\rangle \\
   |0\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-1\rangle \\
   |-1\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{2}|-1\rangle$$
2. $$|1\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle-\frac{1}{2}|-1\rangle \\
   |0\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-1\rangle\\
   |-1\rangle_{x}=\frac{1}{2}|1\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle-\frac{1}{2}|-1\rangle $$

How do we resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The states $|1\rangle_x$, $|0\rangle_x$, and $|-1\rangle_x$ must each be orthogonal to the other two, since they all represent distinct outcomes from an $S_x$ measurement.  One of your proposed sets of eigenstates does not obey this.